# Unable to install Stage 3.2.2 on ubuntu 11.10 64bit

Tags: simulation, stage

I am trying to install stage 3.2.2 on my ubuntu 11.10 64 bit virtual machine. I have already managed to successfully install player 3.0.2.

I have tried every suggested fix online and each has failed.

```
a@ubuntu:~/Stage-3.2.2-Source/build$ make
[ 74%] Built target stage
Linking CXX executable stage
CMakeFiles/stagebinary.dir/main.o: In function `main':
main.cc:(.text.startup+0x304): undefined reference to `Fl::run()'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_File_Chooser::value(int)'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `fl_alert(char const*, ...)'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_Shared_Image::get(char const*, int, int)'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl::repeat_timeout(double, void (*)(void*), void*)'

libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `fl_choice(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, ...)'


libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_File_Chooser::~Fl_File_Chooser()'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_Check_Button::Fl_Check_Button(int, int, int, int, char const*)'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_Widget::default_callback(Fl_Widget*, void*)'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl::e_keysym'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl::delete_widget(Fl_Widget*)'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_Button::Fl_Button(int, int, int, int, char const*)'


libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_Group::find(Fl_Widget const*) const'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_Gl_Window::resize(int, int, int, int)'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_Scroll::Fl_Scroll(int, int, int, int, char const*)'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl::e_state'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_Window::Fl_Window(int, int, char const*)'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `gl_draw(char const*, int, int, int, int, Fl_Align)'

libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `fl_height()'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `typeinfo for Fl_Gl_Window'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_Gl_Window::invalidate()'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_Button::value(int)'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `gl_width(char const*)'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_Gl_Window::flush()'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_Text_Display::buffer(Fl_Text_Buffer*)'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_Window::~Fl_Window()'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
libstage.so.3.2.2: undefined reference to `Fl_Window::show()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libstage/stage] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libstage/CMakeFiles/stagebinary.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: This does not sound like a programming question. You may find more luck on [AskUbuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/), if they allow these types of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest with you I tried as well to install Player/Stage on Ubuntu last year for a group project (i.e. Robot Garbage Collection in an Unknown Environment), but I couldn't find no solution for it. I actually still have a similar question which to this day remains unanswered here on StackOverflow and several other sites. In the end I switched to Fedora which I must say was more hassle free and actually gave me the opportunity to work on the project rather than spend a lot of time trying to solve some godforsaken error.

Comment: Actually, I just remembered that there is a version of Fedora which has already Player/Stage installed for you. Refer to https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Robotics